# Using ThreadPoolExecutor without with statement Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

In my program, I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor to perform some multithreading. Keep in mind I'm pretty new to multithreading, so some of this stuff may be wrong, but normally I do this within a with statement like so:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as pool:
    # some code...
    pool.submit(myFunction)
    # some code...
```

However, in the program I'm working on now I don't think I can use the with statement. I'm using Kivy, a graphics library, to create a GUI and I can't throw the entire code inside of the with statement like I normally do. I can do the following instead, but I'm not sure if there's any clean up that I need to do on the threads that would normally be done by the with statement.

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None)
# some code...
pool.submit(myFunction)
# some code...
```

Thanks for your help!